# How to read a large Rich Text Format(.rtf) file. (such as 30M) with Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos

How to correctly read a large Rich Text Format (*.rtf) files with Objective-C?

E.g.

The file: test.rtf is about 20MB big, and I need to display the content on a `TextView`. In order to load data fast on the screen, I want to read multiple times from test.rtf (256KB byte each time). But when I use:

```
NSFileHandle *fileHandle = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
    NSInteger count = 0;
    NSInteger dataLength = 1024*256;  //256K byte
    NSData *data = [fileHandle readDataOfLength:dataLength];

  NSDictionary *docAttributes;
  NSMutableAttributedString* mutableAttriString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithData:data options:nil documentAttributes:&docAttributes error:&error];
```

Then the `mutableAttriString` will always be `nil`, for the structure of .rtf is destroyed when I don't read the entire .rtf file.

Comment: That's normal no? It's because you haven't a valid rtf file, the tags aren't correct. Also, depending on the encoding, what if you are cutting a “char in two" at the end of 1024*256? Open your file with a simple Text Reader (using more in Terminal, Atom.app, etc) you'll see that you need to read tags.

Comment: 20M is not a big file - read it completely and then create attributed string.

Comment: try this GitHub https://gist.github.com/digitalpardoe/1086559

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the link for github you offered is invalid, could you please check it for me ? Many thanks.@jbiser361

Comment: Thanks everybody, the problem has been worked out by myself. I will give the solutions on github later. Thanks all.

Comment: @Asperi then if the file size is 200M, 2G ?

Comment: RTF? Never see such. Bad luck - you need then to code your own streaming RTF parser, because NSAttributedString requires complete data to be loaded in memory.